# In ExtJs, how to use an icon as "value" of "displayfield"?

Tags: extjs

I wish to have an icon displayed as "value" for a form "displayfield". This is to display read-only values like true/false and yes/no with icons like "tick mark/cross mark". How to do it? There are many posts on labels but that is not what I am looking for. I need a "fieldLabel" and then the icon (it is not mandatory to use a form though, I may use any component for this).

Comment: How? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can do that  try with my example and I am  attaching screenshot too.

```
            Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 200,
            height: 150,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            title: 'Final Score',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'home ',
                name: 'home_score',
                value: '<img src="home.png"></img> '
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Visitor ',
                name: 'visitor_score',
                value: '<img src="visitor.png"></img>'
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Update'
            }]
        });
        });
```

Just change the path of your image in your code.If you are not using form apply the same in label field.[image]

Comment: I actually need image in "value" of displayfield and not in "fieldLabel"

Comment: Then accept my answer :-) People with same issue will get solution immediately

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did the following in items of form-panel to make it work:

```
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'Label 1',
            flex: 1,
            name: 'Name 1',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'image',
                glyph: 'something@FontAwesome'
            }]
        },{
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'Label 2',
            flex: 1,
            name: 'Name 2',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'image',
                glyph: 'something@FontAwesome'
            }]
        }
```

I put Ext.Img in 'requires' of form-panel class.